# TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

```
    {% for frequency in patient_meds.frequency %}
            {% if frequency == "7" %}
            <td>Hellow</td>
            {% endif %}
    {% endfor%}
```

getting error

TemplateSyntaxError: 'if' statement improperly formatted

i don't know what i have to do please help me...

Comment: which django version do you use?

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the default version of Django included with app engine (v0.96), then try this syntax:

```
{% for frequency in patient_meds.frequency %}
        {% ifequal frequency "7" %}
            <td>Hellow</td>
        {% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Happened to me too, notice it's actually should be {% endifequal %} for it to work.

Answer (score 2):

In order to be able to use the `==` syntax in the `{% if %}` statement, you need to use Django 1.2 or above.

Django 1.2 comes with your GAE SDK, but 0.96 is loaded by default.

You can use version 1.2 of django , by declaring the version of the [third-party library](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django) you want to use with the `use_library()` function provided by the `google.appengine.dist` package. Just put this code at the very top of your python file (at least before importing anything from django:

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.2')
```

This way, your template should render nicely.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be `endifequal`:

```
{% for frequency in patient_meds.frequency %}
    {% ifequal frequency "7" %}
        <td>Hellow</td>
    {% endifequal %}
{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `==` syntax in the `{% if %}` tag is only available since version 1.2 of Django :)